# What would be the equation of an elliptical paraboloid which sits on XZ plane?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

$f(x, y) = -x^2-y^2+4$ is the equation of a paraboloid which sits on the XY plane and protrudes toward Z-axis.

[image]

[See the link.](https://academo.org/demos/3d-surface-plotter/?expression=-x%5E2-y%5E2%2B4&xRange=-50%2C%2050&yRange=-50%2C%2050&resolution=47)

So, if I want a paraboloid to be drawn on the surface XZ, I should write: $f(x, z) = -x^2-z^2+4$

My question is, **is it possible to write an equation of a paraboloid as a function of x,y, even though it sits on the surface XZ?**

Why or why not?

Comment: It is not a function, it consists of two braches.  $$y = -x^2 -z^2 + 4 \iff z^2 = 4 - y - x^2 \implies z = \pm \sqrt{4 - y -x^2}$$
To visualize, you can plot individual branch instead.

Comment: No more than you can write $y$ as a function of $x$ for a parabola that opens in the direction of the $x$-axis.